# Windows 10 USB installer cannot boot

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, usb, iso-image

I want to install windows 10 on my Ubuntu machine, of which I recently installed. I downloaded and burned the windows 10 iso from microsoft's website onto a 16gb usb stick.

When I tried to boot from it from my motherboard setting, it would blackscreen for a second and then boot into Ubuntu. I have also tried starting it directly from my boot menu, same problem. The option shows up without a "UEFI:" before the usb stick name.

Burned iso onto usb stick first with [Etcher](https://etcher.io/), didn't work. Thinking it was the usb stick, I burned it onto an 8gb stick that returned the same error. I re-downloaded the iso and repeated the above mentioned steps. I also tried burning it with `dd`, but that also returned the same problem.

The usb stick does not boot on any machine I tried it on, 2 others running Ubuntu and Mint respectively.

My motherboard, a `MSI 970 GAMING` is set to `uefi+legacy` boot mode. I have had problems with the line in the past, resulting in getting another refurbished model, the one I use now.

I have also done a MEMTEST, memory is OK.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but looks like winusb would work http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/make-bootable-windows-10-usb-install.html

Comment: Thanks, this should work. I don't have time to do it at the time of typing this comment, but it seems that simply using `dd` will not work due to win10 being a hybrid OS, as referenced in the comments of what you linked.

Answer (score 0):

From the Etcher Documentation: ["Why is my drive not bootable?"](https://github.com/resin-io/etcher/blob/master/docs/USER-DOCUMENTATION.md#why-is-my-drive-not-bootable):

> Etcher copies images to drives byte by byte, without doing any transformation to the final device, which means images that require special treatment to be made bootable, like Windows images, will not work out of the box. In these cases, the general advice is to use software specific to those kind of images, usually available from the image publishers themselves. Images known to require special treatment: Microsoft Windows (use Windows USB/DVD Download Tool, or Rufus). [...]

So maybe try [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)?

Comment: I eventually got it to work. I generally would use Rufus, but I did not have access to a windows machine so I used winusb. It was my fault for not reading the documentation, didn't realize windows needed special treatment.